# Mouse and Keyboard doesn't recognized after boot- Timeout problem

Tags: boot, keyboard, mouse

My mouse and keyboard use the same dongle to connect to the system.
That mouse and keyboard works correctly on other systems.
I have checked another mouse and keyboard to connect to my system. The result is the same.
The Ubuntu 18.04.5 doesn't recognized them.
Currently I can connect to system through ssh.

Some part of the output of the below command is:

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep device

boltd[6544]: store: loading devices
boltd[6544]: udev: enumerating devices
kernel: [   78.088098] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4016.0005: HID++ 2.0 device connected.
upowerd[6324]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:4016.0005/power_supply/hidpp_battery_1
dev-sdb1.device: Job dev-sdb1.device/start timed out.
Timed out waiting for device dev-sdb1.device.
dev-sdb1.device: Job dev-sdb1.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
Starting Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor...
Started Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor.
dev-sdb1.device: Job dev-sdb1.device/start timed out.
Timed out waiting for device dev-sdb1.device.
dev-sdb1.device: Job dev-sdb1.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
dev-sdb1.device: Job dev-sdb1.device/start timed out.
Timed out waiting for device dev-sdb1.device.
dev-sdb1.device: Job dev-sdb1.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
```

What should I do to come back my system functionality?

if you want any other information let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I have uninstalled `xserver-xorg-input-all` previously.
The main reason of problem is there is no input driver so it couldn't be mounted as a valid device.
So the problem simply can be solved by executing this:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
```